# Is it possible to use the prediction of a CNN for images not belonging to the model classes?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, prediction

I am using photos of faces of individuals of 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, and 20 years old. The question I am trying to answer is: How does the face "evolves"? Will it remain +/- similar until a certain threshold where it will suddenly change?
To answer this question, I trained a CNN on 2 classes, the 10 year old photos (labelled as "0") and the 20 year old photos (labelled as "1").

I used this model to predict the categories that do not belong to the model's classes (the 12 to 18 years old), to compute the average prediction for each age group. The result is shown in the figure, where each value is respectively the mean prediction for 12, 14, 16, 18 years old. [Mean prediction for 12,14,16,18 years old](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YQRR.png)

My question here is : Does it make sense to use this model to predict other age groups and say for example "The 12 years old have a mean prediction of 0.2, which means they are more similar to the 10 years old faces than the 20 years old faces" ?
As the values are increasing with age, can I say that the faces are getting more similar to 20 years old faces ? And are there any references of articles using a model to predict images belonging to none of the model's classes ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an interesting question. Let me answer this in two ways.

---

*Q1: Can CNN predict image whose class is not included in the training set?*

A1: Yes. However, instead of training the model and comparing the output probabilities, we use a method called “few-shot learning”, or “zero-shot learning” to figure this out. The basic idea is: first, we train the model so that it recognizes the high-level features underlying the data (e.g., the edges or the shape of eyes in your example). Then we implement the model to a new dataset, relying on its generalizability. This research is also closely related to transfer learning.
As a starting point, here is a good paper.

[Generalizing from a Few Examples: A Survey on Few-shot Learning](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3386252?casa_token=VTFc9ZdKd5wAAAAA:aRaqLmFNPAIqESe08eOwTn0ba8Nxg-6Wnc-rH0a-LjE_UNhmY0catx6yaC3cIvOV9l-i-qmT9SKp)

---

*Q2: If the probability is higher, can we say the faces are more similar to 20 year old faces?*

A2: **The short answer is, YES.** The reason is that we only have two classes in your training data – if the value of probability is higher, it means the model has more confidence that the picture belongs to the class of 1 (i.e., 20 year old photos). But we cannot make sure how the model makes this prediction. You may want to visualize outputs of intermediate layers to see which feature the model finds. You can have a check at this blog.

[Understanding CNN (Convolutional Neural Network)](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-cnn-convolutional-neural-network-69fd626ee7d4)